# Duplicate Implementation of Methods in Interface. Refactoring

Tags: refactoring, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

Just after a little help!

I'm refactoring some code and was wondering if it is possible to create multiple implementations of a abstract class' method.

Say, in one of my subclass, I have one input property and I therefore have setInput and getInput,
however, in my other subclass I have two input properties and therefore setInput1, setInput2 and getInput1 and getInput2
They all have the same implementation code. Is there a way to refactor this in my abstract class?

Thanks!

I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have two different interfaces depending on the number of parameters, consider using parameters with default values. It is not clear what language you are using, but most languages support something like this pseudo-code:

setInput(var input1, var input2 = NULL)

Comment: I am using Java. Also, I can't seem to do that, I think because input is a boolean type?

Comment: But this is definitely along the lines of what I want to do! :(

Comment: I see, for java it looks like you are basically on the right path. Default params are not supported in java, so as an alternative people use the "builder pattern" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern   which is pretty much what you are already doing...